# How to validate fields in a form based on checkbox selection?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having a customer form, where users can enter their contact details. And also there is checkbox for alternate contact details. I have to validate all the required fields in both sections. I have written like this

```
constructor(private api: ApiService, @Inject(FormBuilder) formBuilder: FormBuilder, validatorService: ValidatorService) {
    this.firstName = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.surName = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.address1 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.address2 = new FormControl('');
    this.zip = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.city = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.state = new FormControl('',validatorService.SelectValidation);

    this.phoneNumber = new FormControl('');
    this.email = new FormControl('');
    this.codeOfOrigin = new FormControl('');
    this.hasAlternateDeliveryAddress = new FormControl('');
    this.isClubMember = new FormControl('');
    this.needNewsletter = new FormControl('');
    this.registerUser = new FormControl('');           
    this.firstNameAlternate = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.surNameAlternate = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.address1Alternate = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.address2Alternate = new FormControl('');
    this.zipAlternate = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.cityAlternate = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.stateAlternate = new FormControl('', validatorService.SelectValidation);
    this.customerFormGroup = formBuilder.group({
        'firstName': this.firstName,
        'surName': this.surName,
        'address1': this.address1,
        'address2': this.address2,
        'zip': this.zip,
        'city': this.city,
        'state': this.state,
        'phoneNumber': this.phoneNumber,
        'email': this.email,
        'codeOfOrigin': this.codeOfOrigin,
        'hasAlternateDeliveryAddress': this.hasAlternateDeliveryAddress,
        'isClubMember': this.isClubMember,
        'needNewsletter': this.needNewsletter,
        'registerUser': this.registerUser,
        'firstNameAlternate': this.firstNameAlternate,
        'surNameAlternate': this.surNameAlternate,
        'address1Alternate': this.address1Alternate,
        'address2Alternate': this.address2Alternate,
        'zipAlternate': this.zipAlternate,
        'cityAlternate': this.cityAlternate,
        'stateAlternate': this.stateAlternate
    });       

}
```

But here , all the fields are being validated. How can I restrict validation for alternate contact details if the users not checked the checkbox ?

Comment: Are you hiding the alternate contact details if checkbox is not checked?

Comment: Please share the concerned html code.

Comment: @AmitMalik I'm hiding alternate contact details if the checkbox is not clicked.

Comment: using ng-hide or ng-if to hide details ?

Comment: using boolean value, im checking

Comment: show the relevant html

Comment: @AmitMalik is there any way to check if the control is already exist in the formbuilder ?

Comment: If you disable fields, they will not be included in the form. So when you toggle the alternative fields, also toggle enable/disable of the fields. If you want further assistance, please provide a plunker :)